# How to handle frequently changing multivalue string fields in SOLR?

Tags: solr, lucene

I have a SOLR (or rather Heliosearch 0.07) core on a single EC2 instance. It contains about 20M documents and takes about 50GB on disc. The core is quite fixed/frozen and performs quite well, if everything is warmed up.

The problem is a multimulti value string field: That field contains assigned categories, which change quite frequently for large parts of the 20M documents. After a commit, the warm up takes way too long to be usable in production.

The field is used only for facetting and filtering. My idea was, to store the categories outside SOLR and to inject them somehow using custom code. I checked quite some approaches in various JIRA issues and blogs, but I could not find some working solution. Item 2 of [this issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-4258?focusedCommentId=13423159&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-13423159) suggests that there is a solution, but I don't get what he's talking about.

I would appreciate any solution which allows me to update my category field without having to re-warmup my caches again afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that JIRA will help you: it seems an advanced topic and most impprtant it is still unresolved so not yet available.

Partial document updates are not useful here because a) it requires everything is stored in your schema b) behind the scenes it does reindex again the whole index

From what you say it seems tou have a one monolithic index: have you considered to split the index vertically using sharding or SolrCloud? In that way each "portion" would be smaller and the autowarm shouldn't be a big problem.